# Как найти базис корневого подпространства линейного оператора?

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

Нашёл корневое подпространство линейного оператора `K = <(1, 1, 1, 1), (-1, 0, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0)>`. Как теперь найти его базис?

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, эти вектора и будут базисом. Они все линейно независимы.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, первый вектор нужно нормализовать до длины равной 1 - и тогда вместе с остальными он составит базис

Answer (score 1):

Вы нашли (каким-то способом) подпространство `K`, заданное четырьмя векторами:

```
v1 = (1,1,1,1)
v2 = (-1,0,0,0)
v3 = (0,-1,0,0)
v4 = (0,0,-1,0)
```

Теперь необходимо найти базис: набор **независимых** векторов, с помощью которых можно выразить любой вектор из подпространства `K`.

В данном случае, максимально возможное число независимых векторов - 4, по размерности векторов входящих в подпространство `K` (у векторов - четыре координаты).

Проверим, является ли набор `{v1,v2,v3,v4}` векторов линейно независимым.

Для этого можно составить матрицу `A`

```
 1  1  1  1
-1  0  0  0
 0 -1  0  0
 0  0 -1  0
```

и посчитать ее определитель:

```
det(A)=1≠0
```

который отличен от нуля, а значит вектора `{v1,v2,v3,v4}` - линейно независимы [(как и замечено в одном из комментариев)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#comment1942561_1124149) и составляют базис подпространства `K`. Заметим, что использование определителя для определения ранга матрицы плохое и неоправданное решение в общем случае, особенно если речь идет о предаставлении числе в компьютере с помощью арифметики с плавающей точкой. В этом случае версии QR-разложения ([rank-revealing модификация](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization)), SVD разложения (а также другие способы) сильно предпочитетельней и с точки зрения надежности, и с точки зрения эффективности.

Теперь, очевидно, что любой вектор из `K` может быть выражен с помощью базиса `{v1,v2,v3,v4}`, и `{v1,v2,v3,v4}` покрывают `R^4`.

Базис [можно нормировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#comment1942689_1124149) (поделить каждый вектор на его длину), однако это необязательно.